# Specifying an empty or nil fixture in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

I have the ff. ActiveRecord which I use only for the ID it generates:

```
class SomeTable < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I thought that one could specify fixtures for it through:

```
one:

two:
```

Which I refer to in other fixtures as:

```
other_one:
  some_field: some value
  some_table: one
```

But when I run my tests, I get:

```
Fixture::FormatError: Bad data for SomeTable fixture named one (nil)
```

Does anybody know how to specify empty or nil fixtures then?  If this is not possible, either a work-around or an alternative solution is acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried doing it without the extra carriage return in between the fixture labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
one:
  id: 1

two:
  id: 2

...
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't set the id explicitly if you want to use the labels as foreign key in some other fixture file.

```
# in users.yml
one: {}

two: {}

# now in posts.yml, this works:
one:
  user: one
```